# Using vectors in C++ to read and write files

Tags: iphone

I want to write a C++ program that reads the contents of a file word by word and puts them into a vector of strings. The program then prints to the screen all the words in the vector each on its line, the total number of words read and then clears all the words from the vector.  Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Have you done anything so far?  Is there a specific part of the problem that's causing you trouble?

Comment: #include <fstream>

Comment: #include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    ifstream in("Myfile.cpp");
    string S;
    while(getline(in,S))
        cout<<S<<"\n";
}
I tried in XCode but its dong nothing when i run. Only writes "Build failed"

Comment: When the build fails, you should be able to look in Xcode's Report Navigator view and see more details about what the compile or link error actually was.

Comment: Thanks I'll check on that!